# Form being handled by wrong view?

Tags: django

At the url `/sites/1` I have a form:

```
<form action="." method="post">
...
```

However when I submit it, it is handled at `/sites/` by a different view, causing an error.

Here is my `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^sites/$', 'app.views.sites_view'),
url(r'^sites/(?P<site_id>\d+)$', 'app.views.site_view'),
...
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URLs are not consistent in their use of trailing slashes.

The browser treats URLs as a directory structure. `.` means the root of the current "directory". If you're at `/sites/1`, then the "current directory" is `/sites/`. If you were at `/sites/1/` - ie with a trailing slash, as recommended in the Django docs - then the current directory will still be `/sites/1/`.

Ensure all your URLs end with slashes, and use the default append slash functionality to redirect to the slash-appended version of any URL.

Answer (score 0):

action should have the {% url current_view_name %} value

e.g.

```
url(r'^sites/$', 'app.views.sites_view'),
url(r'^sites/(?P<site_id>\d+)$', 'app.views.site_view', name="sites_view"),
```